# How is follower DPS calculated?

Tags: diablo-iii

When I equip my follower with a weapon his DPS value changes. But his DPS value is far lower than the weapon's DPS. How is the follower's DPS determined? Is it only some percentage of their weapon's DPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I read here http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5150755834 it seems they made the follower do 15% DPS based on what equipment your follower has. :D